# How to match ANSI data encoded as Unicode with regex

Tags: regex

I have some ANSI data encoded as UTF16 Little Endian.

It therefore looks like `a \0 b \0 c \0`. I suspect this is asking way too much of regex, but just on the off-chance, is there any way of matching this data specifically?

I am able to use `^[\w\x00]+$` but that doesn't really ensure that the null bytes are in the right place. Is there any way to have an alternating pattern match, or match based on character position mod 2 so that the even positions must be filled with null bytes, and null bytes are not allowed elsewhere?

If not I'll write a little bit of manual code, just would be helpful to know.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "ANSI"? (Microsoft has misused that term to refer to data encoded in a Microsoft-specific 8-bit encoding similar to Latin-1). And surely it would be easier to convert it to an 8-bit encoding and apply a regex to the result.

Comment: Yeah, I meant how Microsoft use it by the sounds of it - the null bytes will *always* be null bytes, never used as part of special accents in foreign languages for this particular bit of data. And yes, the conversion is probably the easiest way. I was trying to avoid an if statement though, since the code's currently fairly neat along the lines of `Regex.Match(instanceOfConcreteSubclass.regexVar);`. I guess the way forward is to convert to a `instanceOfConcreteSubclass.RunRegex();` which is probably better in the long term anyway. Thanks for your help!